# EF Core FreeTextTable Can't Get Rank

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am running the following query:
(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT KEY_TBL.RANK, FT_TBL.* 
FROM dbo.Forums AS FT_TBL 
   INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Forums, Title,'{searchTerm}') AS KEY_TBL
      ON FT_TBL.Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

This works great when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio, but when I run it in my API, I do not get the rank. It is always 0.

Here is my model:

```
public class Forum : BaseModel
    {
        public ApplicationUser? ForumAuthor { get; set; }
        public string ForumAuthorId { get; set; } = "";
        
        [Required (AllowEmptyStrings = false,ErrorMessage = "A Title is required")]
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public List<Post>? Posts { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int RANK { get; set; }
    }
```

Notice that RANK has a `[NotMapped]` attribute. I did that because I don't have a RANK field on the Forums table.

So I decided to create a `ForumViewModel` that has a RANK field without the `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Here is my query:

```
List<ForumViewModel> forums = await _context.Forums.FromSqlRaw(forumSql).Select(x => new ForumViewModel()
            {
                ForumAuthor = x.ForumAuthor,
                ForumAuthorId = x.ForumAuthorId,
                Posts = x.Posts,
                RANK = x.RANK,
                Title = x.Title,

            }).ToListAsync();
```

The result is the same. RANK = 0.

If I remove the `[NotMapped]` attribute, I get the rank with a valid number greater than 0. So I believe the `[NotMapped]` attribute is the problem.

The rank is returned by the FREETEXTTABLE. So, I am using DbContext to query my Forums table, joined to FREETEXTTABLE. This table returns the rank of the search term against all text in the title field of the Forums table. Please see the link I put in the beginning of this post.

How can I get the Rank without having to needlessly add the `Rank` field to my `Forum` table.

Edit: Solved
I figured it out. There is a data annotation for this situation:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public int RANK { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I figured it out. There is a data annotation for this situation:
[Generated Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations)

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public int RANK { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there any way to get rank value without raw sql? I tried your solution but it always returns 0.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to use `RANK` without adding it to the entity? Adding it to the entity requires it to exist in the table (e.g. INSERT via EF will fail if the column does not exist) even though it is supposed to be temporary or virtual.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to get rank in linq.  You need to orderbydescending and then group quantities.  See below where I created a dictionary of the values.

```
           int[] quantities = { 49, 49, 41, 30, 17, 35, 25, 24, 14, 12 };

           Dictionary<int, int> rankDictionary = quantities
                .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                //skip zero
                .Select((x, i) => new { quantity = x, index = i + 1 })
                .GroupBy(x => x.quantity, y => y.index)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Min(z => z));
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have explained better. The rank is returned by the FREETEXTTABLE. So, I am using DbContext to query my Forums table, joined to FREETEXTTABLE. This table returns the rank of the search term against all text in the title field of the Forums table. Please see the link I put in the original post.

Comment: Try a RawSQL.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

Comment: I am using Raw SQL. See my post above: '''await _context.Forums.FromSqlRaw'''

Comment: Rank is a function and should have parenthesis.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I figured it out. Rank is not a function in this case. It is a value that is returned by the FREETEXTTABLE function. See my posted answer above, and please see the link I referred you to earlier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Rank is a function.  Your code put the Rank into a temporary table and you query is using the temporary table.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understand that Rank is a function, but I am not using the Rank function.